# Rails, how to know if a particular request is still running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, request, uniqueidentifier

How can I detect if a particular `request` is still active?

For example I have this request uuid:

```
# my_controller.rb
def my_action
    request.uuid # -> ABC1233
end
```

From another request, how can I know if the request with uuid `ABC1233` is still working?

---

*For the curious:*

Following [beanstalk directives](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html#worker-periodictasks) I am running cron jobs using URL requests.

I don't want to start the next iteration if the previous one is still running. I can not just relay in a `ini/end` flag updated by the request because the request some times dies before it finishes.

Using normal cron tasks I was managing this properly using the PID of the process. 
But I don't think I can use PID any more because processes in a web server can be reused among different requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I recovered my previous approach based on PIDs.

I implemented something like this:

```
# The Main Process
module MyProcess
  def self.run_forked
    Process.fork do
      SynchProcess.run
    end

    Process.wait
  end

  def self.run
    RedisClient.set Process.pid # store the PID

    ... my long process code is here
  end

  def self.still_alive?(pid)
    !!Process.kill(0, pid) rescue false
  end
end

# In one thread I can do
MyProcess.run_forked

# In another thread I can do
pid = RedisClient.get
MyProcess.still_alive?(pid) # -> true if the process still running
```

I can call this code from a Rails request and even if the request process is reused the child one is not and I can monitor the PID of the child process to see if the Ruby process is still running.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Rails (or more correctly, Rack) has support for this since (to the best of my knowledge) each Rails request doesn't know about any other requests. You may try to get access to all running threads (and even processes) but such implementation (if even possible) seems ugly to me
.

How about implementing it yourself?

```
 class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
     before_filter :register_request 
     after_filter  :unregister_request 

     def register_request 
        $redis.set request.uuid
     end

     def unregister_request 
         $redis.unset request.uuid
     end
 end
```

You'll still need to figure out what to do with exceptions since after_filters are skipped (perhaps move this whole code to a middleware: on the before phase of the middleware it writes the uuid to redis and on the after phase it removes the key ). There's a bunch of other ways to achieve this I'm sure and obviously substitute redis with your favorite persistence of choice.

Comment: I am implementing something like this but it is not trustable due the request can die or can be killed (in a system level) and the `unset` signal is never sent. This is because I need an external method to know if a request is still alive.

Comment: I'm as lost as u then . You can obviously save timestamps on redis too  and periodically kill "old" ones but u probably know that already. Let me know if you find anything more, it's an interesting problem!